# Is there a way to display a day number using `strftime` without leading space?

Tags: php

According [to the documentation](http://www.php.net/strftime), `strftime` accepts a `%e` character in format parameter that returns the "day of the month, **with a space preceding single digits**".

So if I use it in order to display localized date I've got two different results, if I'm at the beginning of the month or the end of the month:

```
echo strftime('%A %e %B' . PHP_EOL);
// Displays: Monday  5 February

echo strftime('%A %e %B' . PHP_EOL, time() + 400000);
// Displays: Saturday 10 February
```

It's annoying and a bit weird. I don't know why this space is here (historical reasons?), I don't see any case where it's useful. But that's not the real question.

Is there a way to display a day number using `strftime` without leading space (and without leading zero)?

Comment: `I don't know why this space is here`->which spaces you are talking about?

Comment: As far as I know there aren't undocumented codes. It should be trivial though to strip extraneous spaces.

Comment: @AlivetoDie in `Monday  5 February`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Click on the documentation link in the question. It explains that `%e` is "Day of the month, with a space preceding single digits".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "brute-force" method is always an option:

```
echo strftime('%A '), trim(strftime('%e')), strftime(' %B'), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: what about if he want to add 400000 too?

Comment: `$ts = time() + 40000; echo strftime('%A', $ts), ...`

Answer (score 2):

On Linux (though not Windows) C's `strftime` (which is presumably the same as PHP's) takes `-` to remove padding, i.e. the following might work:

```
echo strftime('%A %-e %B' . PHP_EOL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `str_replace()` :

```
echo str_replace('  ', ' ', strftime('%A %e %B' . PHP_EOL));
```

Comment: Ok so brute-force too :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **trim()** function:

```
trim( strftime('%e') )
```

trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php